# Align text in list item with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have basic list item and am trying to achieve that this longer text doesn't wrap below the icon, see my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>uuu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        li {
            list-style: none;
        }

        section {
            width: 240px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            padding: 102px 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 19;
        }

        li>a {
            padding: 0.85rem 0rem;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 2px;
            list-style-position: outside;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: #646b71;
            transition: background-color 300ms, color 300ms;
            font-weight: 500;
            display: block;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        li>a>i {
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            position: relative;
            top: 0.1rem;
            width: 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: 0.6rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <li class="ja">
            <a href="#" class="">
                <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis unde</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

Can somebody try to help me with this? Note* this code structure needs to stay the same if you know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
    <title>uuu</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        
      .hash-a {
        display: flex;
      }

        section {
            width: 240px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            padding: 102px 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 19;
        }

        li>a {
            padding: 0.85rem 0rem;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 2px;
            list-style-position: outside;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: #646b71;
            transition: background-color 300ms, color 300ms;
            font-weight: 500;
            display: block;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        li>a>i {
            vertical-align: top;
            font-size: 1.3rem;
            position: relative;
            top: 0.1rem;
            width: 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: 0.6rem;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <li class="ja">
            <a href="#" class="hash-a">
                <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis unde</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

how about add another class for the a tag? See the code above

Answer (score 0):

The CSS ***Lists and Counters Module Level 3*** introduces the ::marker pseudo-element. From what I've understood it would allow such a thing. Unfortunately, no browser seems to support it.

What you can do is add some padding to the parent ul and pull the icon into that padding:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}
li:before {
  content: "\f00c"; /* FontAwesome Unicode */
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */
  width: 1.3em; /* same as padding-left set on li */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   
 <ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
</ul>
```